# Change image source with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, src

So I'm new with JavaScript (this is actually my first attempt to make something work) and I'm having a bit of trouble. I thought I had enough knowledge to make this work, I've even googled for tutorials and scripts that could help me work this out but nothing really helped.

I can't seem to change the image source, heres the code that I have so far:

```js
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("img").src=a.src;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main_img">
        <img id="img" src="1772031_29_b.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="thumb_img">
        <img src='1772031_29_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_29_b.jpg");'>
        <img src='1772031_55_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_55_b.jpg");'>
        <img src='1772031_53_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_53_b.jpg");'>
    </div>
```

Could anyone please explain if I'm doing something wrong? Or maybe I'm missing something? Help me please :-)

Answer (score 30):

`function changeImage(a)` so there is no such thing as `a.src` => just use `a`.

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/7wpAw/)

Comment: I was also missing the " " like ShaneC said hehe but I see you also added it to the demo. Thank you very much

Answer (score 16):

If you will always have the pattern on `_b` instead of `_t` you can make it more generic by passing reference to the image itself:

```
onclick='changeImage(this);'
```

Then in the function:

```
function changeImage(img) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace("_t", "_b");
}
```

Comment: Yup this also solved it and the code looks a bit cleaner on the HTML part. Thank you.

Comment: It would be even simpler: `function changeImage(img) {
    img.src = img.src.replace("_t", "_b");
}`. Tested on FF34.0.5

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis it might be simpler, but it's wrong. It's bad practice to count on the browser to fix our mistakes as developers.

Answer (score 5):

Your only real problem is you are passing a string, not an object with a `.src` property

Some suggestions:

- Use a naturally clickable element trigger, such as `<button>`
- Use `data-` prefixed attributes for event data on the element
- Use late bound events when the DOM is ready.

Markup:

```
<div id="main_img">
  <img id="img" src="1772031_29_b.jpg">
</div>
<ul id="thumb_img">
  <li><button data-src='1772031_29_b.jpg'><img src='1772031_29_t.jpg' /></button></li>
  <li><button data-src='1772031_55_b.jpg'><img src='1772031_55_t.jpg' /></button></li>
  <li><button data-src='1772031_53_b.jpg'><img src='1772031_53_t.jpg' /></button></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

If you need to support IE and other legacy browsers, Use a proper [polyfill for Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)

```
function clickedButton(btn, event) {
  document.getElementById('img').src = btn.getAttribute('data-src');
}

function bindClick(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', clickedButton.bind(null,btn));
}

// Setup click handler(s) when content is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#thumb_img > button'))
    .forEach(bindClick));
});
```

---

Edit: Vanilla JS for modern browsers.

Answer (score 5):

I also tube that problem. But solve it by an instance of an image every time you change the source (image).

It seems that would be called onload only once.
But this way, you can change image whenever you want.

```
function chageIcon(domImg,srcImage)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function()
        {
            // Load completed
            domImg.src = this.src;
        };
        img.src = srcImage;
    }
```

Mode use.

```
chageIcon(document.getElementById("img"),"newIcon.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few changes (this assumes you indeed still want to change the image with an ID of IMG, if not use Shadow Wizard's solution).

Remove `a.src` and replace with `a`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=a;
}
</script>
```

Change your `onclick` attributes to include a string of the new image source instead of a literal:

```
onclick='changeImage( "1772031_29_b.jpg" );'
```

Comment: I should have known better than to add those apostrophes ^^ Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you were using `.src` without needing it and
you also needed to differentiate which `img`  you wanted to change.

```js
function changeImage(a, imgid) {
    document.getElementById(imgid).src=a;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_img">
    <img id="img" src="1772031_29_b.jpg">
</div>
<div id="thumb_img">
    <img id="1" src='1772031_29_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_29_b.jpg", "1");'>
    <img id="2" src='1772031_55_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_55_b.jpg", "2");'>
    <img id="3" src='1772031_53_t.jpg'  onclick='changeImage("1772031_53_b.jpg", "3");'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Following Example Program used to change the image src attribute for every 100 milliseconds. you may call the given function as your wish.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="bulboff.jpg" height=200 width=200 id="imm" align="right">

<script type="text/javascript">

function bulb() {

var b = document.getElementById("imm");

if(b.src.match("bulboff.jpg")) {
 b.src = "bulbon.jpg";
}
 else {

 b.src="bulboff.jpg";
}
}
 setInterval(bulb,100);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=a.src;
}
</script>
```

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(a) {
document.getElementById("img").src=a;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but for the one's what are new, here is what you can do:

HTML

```
<img id="demo" src="myImage.png">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('demo').src = "myImage.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage(a) {
    var picName=a.substring(1,a.length-1);
            document.getElementById("image").src=picName;
        }
 </script>

 <div id="main_img">
     <img id="image" src="app.jpg">
 </div>

 <div id="thumb_img">
     <img src='app.jpg'  onclick="changeImage('+5steps.jpg+');">
     <img src='5steps.jpg'  onclick="changeImage('+award.png+');">
     <img src='award.png'  onclick="changeImage('+app.jpg+');">
 </div>
```

Use the above code by placing this html file and pics(take care in namings, beacause I have given the above code with my pic names) in same folder
you will get...

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
function changeimage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('imagem');
    if (image.src.match("img")) {
        for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            image.src = "img/image2"+i+".png";
        }
    } else {
        image.src = "img/image1.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first we have this image1 displayed:

```
<input id="img_prod" type="image" src="img/image1.png" height="400" width="400"
                            onclick ="location.href=this.src">
```

onclick to display the image full screen

and we have other image2

```
<input type="image" src="img/image2.png" height="75" width="75"
                 onclick="document.getElementById('img_prod').src = this.src;">
```

onclick we replace image1 by image2