# changing image source with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, src

So im new with javascript and found this one to solve my problem:

[Change image source with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312553/change-image-source-with-javascript)

But the example does not work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src=a;
  }
</script>
```

And

```
<table align=left width="896px" class="tableCategories">
  <tr class="trCategories">
    <td class="tdCategories">
      <img id="img1" src="./icon/menu/Essen3.png" onclick='changeImage(Shopping3.png);'/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if i click on the image it does not change itself. The path to the images are correct.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: add double quotes around Shopping3.png

Comment: change to onclick='changeImage("Shopping3.png");

Comment: Put quotes around the file name when you call your function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<img id="img1" src="./icon/menu/Essen3.png" onclick='changeImage(Shopping3.png);'/>
```

To

```
<img id="img1" src="./icon/menu/Essen3.png" onclick='changeImage("./icon/menu/Shopping3.png");'/>
```

A better javascript function would be re-usable. Try this:

```
function changeImage(obj,img) {
  obj.src = img;
}
```

and the following HTML code:

```
<img id="img1" src="./icon/menu/Essen3.png" onclick='changeImage(this,"./icon/menu/Shopping3.png");'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass Shopping3.png as a string.

```
<img id="img1" src="./icon/menu/Essen3.png" onclick="changeImage('Shopping3.png');"/>
```