# how to display sequence of images two by two in html?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to display a group of images one by one.that is if first 5 images are displayed then next 5 images should replace them periodically.this should be in loop manner.i didn't get the logic.can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: You should always give what you tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: User a [timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer) then just change the [file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312553/change-image-source-with-javascript). Our website may not have your entire question. However, you can find all the little pieces and stitch the logic together.

Answer (score 0):

on a webpage, right? You probably want to use jquery and some jquery slider/ plugin. Try this: http://www.jssor.com/