# How to create a Build-your-own xy using Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am looking to build a web app that allows you to pick from options like color and size, essentially custom building your own item. Similar to this: http://www.mangobikes.co.uk/bikes/custom/custom-build-your-single-speed-bike

It needs to allow me to display different pictures depending on the choices, and its supposed to have 5 dropdown menus with options. Those options also have submenus to pick colors from.
I am new to Java, and not sure where to start. Is there maybe a good how-to somewhere on the internet? And if not, any hints on how to set it all up?
Thank you

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Read some documentation or something and try it out yourself first.

Comment: Do a programming tutorial which you can find through google.

Comment: @takendarkk yeah thanks I was hoping for something more specific. Ive had a look around and couldnt find anything fitting :-(

Comment: @Arc676 Gee thanks for the passive aggressive. Tell me where I asked someone else to write it? Oh yeah I didnt. All I asked for is a pointer in the right direction. Which I believe many others on here have done, without any sarcastic comments. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, all questions that involve "how do I do this" but show no code get down-voted because it implies that you didn't try before hand. The tooltip for down-voting actually says "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: [The Enterprise Java Tutorials by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/) or just [The Java Tutorials by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/).

Comment: @Arc676 gasp a downvote. however shall I live with myself. Nah, I did try, but beyond being able to create a single tree, I couldnt come up with anythng useful. And besides since I specified that I dont know where to start really, this is slightly redundant.

Comment: @takendarkk :-) Im looking through their version of a tree right now :-) I didnt realize their tutorials were so in-depth. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to answer such a broad question (and that's why it is downvoted), but sometimes it is also difficult for beginners to know where to look.

So some pointers then:

- The first thing you want: *"display different pictures depending on the choices, and its supposed to have 5 dropdown menus with options"* is a matter of web user interface, so you can solve it with basic javascript and HTML (see [Change image source with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312553/change-image-source-with-javascript) as an example). You can do that in an offline html file (you don't need java for it).
- Then I assume that you need some kind of backend to send the selected values and do whatever you need with them. Without more information and assuming you want to do it with java, maybe a good alternative to prototype it could be the [spark java](http://sparkjava.com) framework.