# how to change source image in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change imagesource with another image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("imgbulb").onclick= function() {        

         document.getElementById("imgbulb").Src ="C:\Html\images\ bbc.png";

    }

</script>
```

Comment: probably a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312553/change-image-source-with-javascript In your case, try to use a lower-case `src`.

Comment: I have already tried with lower case 'src' but it didn't work.

Comment: Your browser is sandbox-ed and does does not have access to your local file system like this "C:\Html\images\bbc.png". Try something like "file://relative-path-to-file".

Comment: this is my modified code <body>
 <h1>My first javascript </h1>
 
 <img id="imgbulb" src="images\pic_bulboff.gif" >

  
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  document.getElementById("imgbulb").onclick= function() {  
    
    document.getElementById("imgbulb").src =  "images\pic_bulbon.gif" ;
   
  }

 </script>
  
</body>

Comment: Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Varn/hcbnr0jf/)

Comment: For starters, try this `console.log("C:\Html\images\ bbc.png")`. - recall that in JS as with many languages, `\` is used to escape characters. E.g `\n`, `\t`. You can use two of them or you can reverse them and use forward slashes. I.e `\\` or `/` - this is the strings covered, but there are other issues too. :)

Answer (score 0):

use relative path

```
document.getElementById("imgbulb").onclick= function() {        

     document.getElementById("imgbulb").src ="images/bbc.png";

}
```